# getting infos from information_schema sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following request :

```
SELECT
    tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND ccu.table_name = 'myTable'
```

Which gave me back result when I query in psql or datagrip. When I use sqlalchemy it gives me nothing (ResultProxy with 0 rowcount). Is is some kind of limitation ?

requesting with sqlalchemy :

```
db_engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:5432/myDb')
con = db_engine.connect()
req = '''SELECT
        tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name,
        ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
        ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name
    FROM
        information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
          ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
        JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
          ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
    WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND ccu.table_name = 'myTable' '''
con.execute(req)
// 0 result :-(
```

Comment: Are you using the same user to connect that you're using when you use psql / datagrip?

Comment: No I do not, and you are right, my app have a special user that have right for all the table, but not in information schema... So dumb... This is weird in fact because It doesn't raise error but instead return nothing...

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html: The view `table_constraints` contains all constraints belonging to tables *that the current user owns or has some privilege other than SELECT on*. The same applies to other such views.